# JPA @PreUpdate is not called

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Could someone explain to me the reason of the following behavior?

`EntityA` is being first created and then persisted using `em.persist(..)` method. `@PrePersist` callback is executed before the transaction ends. It works fine.

In the new transaction `EntityA` is obtained using em query. Then, some operations modifying its persistable fields are executed and this transaction ends. But on `em.flush()`, the `@PreUpdate` method is never called nor is `@PrePersist` (the latter I anticipated). Why?

**// EDIT**

That's the trace just before failure. "Done materializing entity" is the effect of the first operation in the transaction that fails.

```
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.example.entity#1]
DEBUG: org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades
DEBUG: org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl - Mark transaction for rollback
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@341a736]
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - rolling back
DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - rolled JDBC Connection
```

Thanks!

Comment: Ensure that you are modifying something that is persisted to EntityA and therefore invalidates the state. If you change a transient it will not call preUpdate.

Answer (score 5):

In the new transaction, `@PrePersist` would be called if you performed a `merge` to update `EntityA`'s state. Simply modifying `EntityA`'s persistent fields without a merge will not result in a call to `@PrePersist`

It is similar for `@PreUpdate`, however is not guaranteed that the `PreUpdate` callback is invoked when an entity is persisted and then modified in a single transaction (which is not the case in your example).

If you are using a *transaction-scoped container-managed entity manager*, then when a transaction ends, those entities become detached. This is likely what is happening when your first transaction completes. These detached entities  will continue to live outside of the persistence context in which they were persisted, however the state of those entities are **no longer** guaranteed to be synchronized with the database. To ensure their state is synchronized, you should perform a `merge` in your second transaction. This will cause the resulting entity to be managed by the persistence context and thus able to be synchronized with the database.

If you don't like this behavior you can choose to use an *extended persistence context*.

Comment: So why PreUpdate callback isn't called? It's persisted in one transaction (then @PrePersist is called), and modified in the other (but then PreUpdate is not called).

Comment: If you turn on tracing, do you see actual database update occur in the second transaction?

Comment: Please see my updated question. It does not suggest anything is being updated... does it? And it surely is java-wise. Three fields that are mapped into the database are changed.

Comment: i added some additional information to my answer that may help

Comment: Didn't help. I'd rather not use an extended persistence context.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `@Transactional` & `@Modifying` were missing in Service layer update method.